# Unity C# Process.GetProcesses() yields different results in editor vs runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to kill "explorer" when my Unity app is running. 
In the editor, by using System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer"); I'm able to find and to kill the process without issue.

However, using the same code in the compiled app returns an empty array. Printing out all the available processes with Process.GetProcesses() I notice that in the editor I have access to many more processes then I do in the compiled app.

I've tried running the compiled app as admin and I've also tried running the app from C:\Program Files with the same result.

My workaround for the time being is to run a .bat file from my unity app that kills windows explorer.

I'm not sure what the issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: More than likely it is because it is a trusted app.  I am having trouble understanding why you would kill explorer especially with a Unity app?

Comment: This is for a touch screen kiosk. In newer versions of Windows, MS has added global gestures (such as swipe from off screen) that gives the user the ability to exit the app or access other portions of the os. There are a few ways to disable these global gestures but they don't work with all hardware configurations. Killing the explorer is the only sure fire way I've found to disable these features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: In the build settings I changed the app to 64bit (x86_64). Once I did this the complied app had access to all the processes including explorer.